# ms-access shorten vba code

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using the following code alot in my project:

```
txtVoornaam.Locked = False
txtVoornaam.BorderStyle = 4
txtVoornaam.BorderColor = RGB(255, 165, 0

txtAchternaam.Locked = False
txtAchternaam.BorderStyle = 4
txtAchternaam.BorderColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)

txtAfdeling.Locked = False
txtAfdeling.BorderStyle = 4
txtAfdeling.BorderColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)
```

I wonder if there is a way to not display this in my code or shorten this. The code gets very long if i use this a few times..

Comment: is this in response to a user activity or in set up?  I would add an array, say `arrControlsResponseToSelection` and then loop this applying the 3 style settings.  Or loop names, with names like `UI_Response_txtAfdeling`

Comment: Your question isn't off-topic per-se, but note that if you're looking for ways to improve your already-working code, or just some feedback on any/all aspects of your working code ("working" is crucially important), then you'll be happy to hear about [codereview.se], where you *present* your code and tell reviewers what it does and how it does it, and reviewers then proceed to help you make it bullet-proof, readable, maintainable, extensible, secure, performant, etc.

Comment: Are these text controls? Iterate through the collection and set the properties of each item that matches an array of the names.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you need to *repeat* a set of instructions, instead of copy+pasta'ing code your first reaction should be to ask yourself "how can I avoid copying this chunk over and over?" - and the solution is pretty much always to *extract a method* and parameterize it.

So you take one of the repeated chunks:

```
txtAchternaam.Locked = False
txtAchternaam.BorderStyle = 4
txtAchternaam.BorderColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)
```

and then copy it one last time in a new scope:

```
Private Sub RenameMe()
    txtAchternaam.Locked = False
    txtAchternaam.BorderStyle = 4
    txtAchternaam.BorderColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)
End Sub
```

Then you extract the parameters:

```
Private Sub RenameMe(ByVal target As Control)
    target.Locked = False
    target.BorderStyle = 4
    target.BorderColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)
End Sub
```

Then you replace the repeated chunks with calls to that new procedure:

```
RenameMe txtVoornaam
RenameMe txtAchternaam
RenameMe txtAfdeling
```

Or if that's still tedious you can iterate controls and call that procedure in the loop body - whatever works best for you.

And if you need more flexibility, extract more parameters and make them `Optional` as needed:

```
Private Sub RenameMe(ByVal target As Control, Optional ByVal lockCtrl As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal brdrStyle As Long = 4, Optional ByVal brdrColor As Long = 42495)
    target.Locked = lockCtrl
    target.BorderStyle = brdrStyle
    target.BorderColor = brdrColor
End Sub
```

Now the hard part is to give `RenameMe` a meaningful name that properly conveys what's going on here. I'd suggest `FormatControl` or something along these lines.

Comment: yes, `target as control` would work better.  I rushed my answer through.

Answer (score 2):

An option if you have several controls that you are creating through a form would be to do the following:

```
Dim names() As String
names = Split("txtVoornaam,txtAchternaam,txtAfdeling", ",")

Dim ctrl As Variant
Dim ctrlName As Variant

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
  For Each ctrlName In names
    If StrComp(ctrlName, ctrl.Name) = 0 Then
        ctrl.Locked = False
        ctrl.BorderStyle = 4
        ctrl.BorderColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)
    End If
  Next ctrlName
Next ctrl
```

This code iterates through each of the control names that fit your list.

However, this is much less efficient than Mat's Mug's answer because you are iterating through the entire list of controls in your form, but it does showcase how you might take a list of static names and iterate through them and a collection.

If you wanted to change all the text controls this would be the way to do it; simply remove the ctrlName check.

As [Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait) has correctly pointed out, you could shorten the code to the following if you are confident in your control names:

```
Dim names() As String
names = Split("txtVoornaam,txtAchternaam,txtAfdeling", ",")

Dim ctrlName As Variant

For Each ctrlName In names
  With Me.Controls(ctrlName)
      .Locked = False
      .BorderStyle = 4
      .BorderColor = RGB(255, 165, 0)
  End With
Next ctrlName
```

Comment: May not need outer loop as you can reference control by name: `Me.Controls(ctrlName).Locked=False...`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Lockdown(strControl)

with me(strControl)
   .locked = false
   .borderstyle = 4
   .bordercolor = RGB(255,165,0)
end with
```

use me or forms!formname depending on where you're calling from

Comment: Rushed answers can always be edited+improved - e.g. complete the scope with `End Function`, fix capitalization, declare explicit types, pass parameters by value - passing a control's name works just as good. But I would avoid Systems Hungarian notation and favor explicit typing, and since there's no need to return anything I'd make it a `Sub`, not a `Function`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @Mat'sMug I saw that after regarding the function. Didn't bother with the `End Function` as I was just showing the parameter.  (Not sure if I should bother editing my answer as your response seems to spell it out much clearer)

Answer (score 0):

if your controls are the same, obviously put them in a single sub/function that you can call from anywhere. i would not try to lock or change the format of textboxes, instead just enable/disable, and it will handle the format for you:

textbox.enabled = true/false

if you are doing this on multiple forms and really want a single sub/function to control enabling/disabling the textboxes on each form, then there are various ways of doing that as well, solution will depend on your needs, but certainly doable and some have already commented above.

for example, you can use the "tag" property of the textboxes to flag the textboxes on that form that you want to enable/disable. you can then have a single sub/function that would take in the form as reference, and then you can read the "tag" property of all textboxes on that form and if they are the ones you flagged, you would proceed to enable/disable them